# XPath - How to select all anchor tags - children and grandchildren

Tags: testing, xpath

For following html sample, how do I get all anchor tags including children and grandchildren?

I have used the following

```
xPath = "//div[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_QuickLaunchNavigationManager']//a"
```

But it only can get the first level of anchor tags.

[image: sample]

Comment: What do you mean by *"first level of anchor tags"*? `//a` is selecting **all** anchors (children + descendants). Make sure that HTML that you're handling *really looks like the one on picture*!

Comment: May be you are saying catch `//a` inside `div` which `@id` is `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_QuickLaunchNavigationManager `and its only one time in your html. your XPath is correct.

Comment: Hi Andersson, this html has child UL inside another li within the selected DIV. It looks like I can only get the first set of links but not the one level deeper links. Like: <ul><li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li><li class="hcf-selected">...<ul><li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li></ul></li> - I can edit the original post more to clarify.

Comment: Hi Amrendra, yes, DIV id ct100_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar-QuickLaunchNavigationManger is only one time found on the page. I want to select all anchor tags including the ones inside child UL/LI.